# Jquery DateTimepicker calendar missing values in safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, safari

I am using the jquery datepicker with the timeplugin. This works on every browser bar Safari which many of our userbase use.

```
    $( '#my_date' ).datetimepicker(
    {
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate: new Date() - 1,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss'
    });
```

The callander on the datepicker shows as undefined  and month days are missing in safari. Can anyone provide some advice?

Comment: Can you show us what's happening in developer console ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**working demo for Safari** http://jsfiddle.net/jT5Gk/4/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/jT5Gk/5/

I noticed the behaviour in Safari and got your point man.

So, I have added the before issue and after issue resolved pics :) to make it clear for other in safari. I can see in safari browser and the problem is the `mindate: new date() -1` which is not correct.

You should also look into here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp
hope it helps and *just extra bit* using datepicker I did  http://jsfiddle.net/2qzjg/

**code**

```
$('#example16_start').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: new Date(-1) ,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss'
});​
```

**OR**

```
  $('#example16_start').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate: -1,
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss'
    });​
```

**Problem was (In Safari)**

[image]

**After Solution Behaves fine**

[image]

Comment: @marabutt No worries, Glad it helped! B-)